# Complicated MySQL Join

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT Project.*, `trk_deleted`, `trk_status`, `trk_state` 
   FROM `project` AS `Project` LEFT JOIN `trackline` ON `prj_id` = `trk_project` 
   WHERE `prj_deleted` = '0' GROUP BY `prj_id` ORDER BY `prj_name`;
```

This is a bit hard to explain, but basically, I have a structure in my database where *Projects* have multiple *Tracklines*. Both of these entities have fields `prj_deleted` and `trk_deleted` respectively which can have a 1 value if it was deleted (hidden from view), or a 0 value is it is not deleted (still in view).

My Project view page shows icons for each project based on the tracklines in that project. These icons are displayed based on the values of `trk_status` and `trk_state`

My Project view page should only show the project 1 time, even if it has multiple tracklines (hence the GROUP BY `prj_id`)

**My Problem:**

From the Mysql Documentation on GROUP BY:

> "Furthermore, the selection of values from each group cannot be influenced by adding an ORDER BY clause. Sorting of the result set occurs after values have been chosen, and ORDER BY does not affect which values the server chooses."

My Project view page should ideally be displaying the icons for the tracklines that are not deleted. This is why I was hoping I could ORDER BY `trk_deleted` before the GROUP BY occurred so that grouping was done with a trackline that wasn't deleted.

Hopefully someone can understand what I'm trying to get at here.

Comment: If a project can have multiple current `trk_status` and `trk_state`, it is a data integrity problem and there can be anomalies in the data.  Is there only one `trackline` per project (and the rest are kept for storage purposes)?  What does it mean for a Project to have two tracklines and both `trk_status`es being valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you could provide some sample data and what you would like for the response, I could probably help with a better query. In the mean time:

```
SELECT Project.*, MAX(`trk_deleted`), MAX(`trk_status`), MAX(`trk_state`)
FROM `project` AS `Project` 
LEFT JOIN `trackline` ON `prj_id` = `trk_project` AND trk_deleted = '0'
WHERE `prj_deleted` = '0'
GROUP BY `prj_id` ORDER BY `prj_name`;
```

Comment: Joining with a second condition trk_deleted = '0' did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, you want to get all projects that are not deleted, having tracklines or not, and the tracklines that are not deleted. But adding `trk_delete = 0` excludes the projects that do not have tracklines.

I'm not very familiar with mysql, but i think that you want is IS NULL

```
SELECT 
    Project.*, 
    `trk_deleted`, 
    `trk_status`, 
    `trk_state` 
FROM 
    `project` AS `Project` 
LEFT JOIN 
    `trackline` ON `prj_id` = `trk_project` 
WHERE 
    `prj_deleted` = '0' 
    AND trk_deleted = '0' OR trk_deleted IS NULL
GROUP BY 
    `prj_id` 
ORDER BY 
    `prj_name`
```

If that's not it, please clarify yourself